# How to make an animation work with animejs?

Tags: javascript, animation, dom-events

This is the part of the HTML that really matters:-

```
<div id = 'buttons'>
            <a href = 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=775316623220277248&permissions=391232&scope=bot' target = '_blank'>
                <button id = 'invbutton'><i class="fab fa-discord fa-3x"></i>Invite</button>
            </a>
            <button>Support</button>
</div>
```

This is the JS:-

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    let current_button = buttons[i];
    buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        console.log(current_button)
        anime({
            target: current_button,
            scale: 2,
            translateX: 500,
            duration: 5000
        })
        console.log("temp")
    })
}
```

I have established the script at the end of the HTML file. The script console logs both the time correctly but the animation does not occur

Comment: A `<button>` inside of an `<a>` does not make sense; it is invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo. Its supposed to be `targets` not `target`